# How can I get the associations from the polymorphic class to the related classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I am trying to get some polymorphic associations to work properly but I am unable to get them right. Currently they give me whatever the ID matches for both tables instead of the direct relation.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :origin, polymorphic: true
  has_one :customer, foreign_key: :id, primary_key: :origin_id, class_name: "Customer"
  has_one :employee, foreign_key: :id, primary_key: :origin_id, class_name: "Employee"
end

class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :user, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :origin_id
end

class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :user, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :origin_id
end
```

If I do:

```
user = User.create(origin: Customer.find(1))
user.customer # => #<Customer:0x000000014a78d2c8>
# I expect that the code below to be nil but it is not
user.employee # => #<Employee:0x000000014a78d2c8>
```

Does anyone know how can I get the proper association? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In the rails guides there is example with [`has_many`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) polymorphic associations

`has_one` has almost the same code, also read more about [`belongs_to`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to) association options

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :origin, polymorphic: true

  belongs_to :customer, -> { where(users: { origin_type: 'Customer' }).includes(:user) }, foreign_key: :origin_id
  belongs_to :employee, -> { where(users: { origin_type: 'Employee' }).includes(:user) }, foreign_key: :origin_id

  # Or simply define instance methods if you don't need above associations:
  # def customer
  #   origin if origin_type == 'Customer'
  # end

  # def employee
  #   origin if origin_type == 'Employee'
  # end
end

class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :user, as: :origin
end

class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :user, as: :origin
end
```

In any case you need such schema migration:

```rb
create_table :users do |t| # or change_table if it is existing table
  t.belongs_to :origin, polymorphic: true # origin_id and origin_type columns
end
```

Output should be something like this

```
user = User.create(origin: Customer.find(1))
user.customer # => #<Customer:0x000000014a78d2c8>
user.employee # => nil
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately this does not work for me as I need to be able to do  joins as well.

Comment: @VictorLuna I've added to the answer example with `belongs_to` association

Answer (score 0):

First there are a couple of things that need to be changed.You don't need to define separate associations for customer and employee as you will be using a polymorphic association and don't need to explicitly specify the primary keys and foreign keys.

So We should change the code as follows:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :origin, polymorphic: true
end

class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :user, as: :origin
end

class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :user, as: :origin
end
```

For learning on how this works, I suggest you to go through official docs on
active record associations https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

And for getting the user record from customer or employee you can use `customer.origin` or `employee.origin` respectively.
if you wish to get the associated origin type of user you can use `user.origin.origin_type`

Comment: OP need to call `user.customer` / `user.employee` methods